# How do I disable (video) thumbnails in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails

I'd like to turn off Windows 7 (video) thumbnails displayed in Explorer.  I found this solution for Windows XP but it doesn't work for Windows 7 ("The module shmedia.dll failed to load").

[Disable thumbnails in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/133188/disable-thumbnails-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable video thumbnails only, download and run [ShellExView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) (a great system tool from NirSoft). 
Disable the "MF XXX Property Handler" lines. Close and restart explorer windows. You are done :)

screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQhMU.png]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on ShellExView. I used it to disable thumbnail preview for another file type (LibreOffice ods file) by disabling "<program name> Thumbnail Viewer" and restarting the explorer.exe process.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of potential options.

1. Open `Explorer`/`Tools`/`Folder options`/`View` and check the first box `Always show icons, never thumbnails`
2. You can customize the way way each folder controls the display of the objects within. Right click on a folder and choose `Properties` then `Customize` In the drop down list for `Optimize this folder for`, select `General items`
3. Changing the `View` type will work too.

Comment: Thanks, the second option worked great (first option would remove other functionality I want to keep, image thumbnails).

Comment: Hmm...  I just tried this in Windows 7 and it didn't remove the thumbnails from the video files contained in the folder.