# Force Windows 7 to store thumbnails locally

Tags: windows-7, windows, cache, thumbnails

I want Windows 7 to store thumbnails cache files in the same folder as the files (thumbs.db) instead of using the centralized location for all thumbnails (By default %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer). How would one achieve this effect?

Alternatively, if the former is implausible, I'd settle for no thumbnail caching at all, forcing Windows to regenerate thumbnails each time a folder is accessed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable (video) thumbnails in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/152272/how-do-i-disable-video-thumbnails-in-windows-7)

Comment: Windows 7 always uses the central DB instead of Thumbs.db in each folder, unless the target folder is remote (ie: network share on a different machine).

Comment: @techie007 this question is about disabling (centralized) caching of thumbnails. The question you linked is about disabling thumbnails. There is 0 overlap between the 2 topics.

Comment: "if the former is implausible, I'd settle for no thumbnail caching at all".  I don't believe it's possible to force it to use Thumbs.db everywhere, and I don't believe you can have Thumbnails without a cache.  So I offered the Dupe as it meets your alternative request "no caching", unfortunately the side effect is no Thumbnails.  But remember, it says "possible", and it takes more than one vote to close. :)  Maybe someone has an answer, or maybe 4 more people will come along and feel it's the same problem, with the same answer. The joys of community...

Comment: @techie007 if you think the answer is "it's impossible" you should still post it and provide a link to the alternative, not cast a fallacious close vote.