# How to show icons for some file types and thumbnails for others?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, thumbnails

How can I control which file types are shown as thumbnails and which as icons?
I do think that showing these tiny little thumbnails for things like text file or spreadsheet is utterly stupid. You can't see a thing on that, and you have to guess what file type you are looking at.

I know that I can set explorer to show only icons (`Always show icons, never thumbnails`), but that's not the solution because then I can't see jpeg thumbnails. I would like to show thumbnails only for image files and disable them for files like pdf, xps, docx, xlsx and similar. Is there a tool for that?

Setting this on "by folder" basis (`Optimize this folder for`) isn't solution either.

Update:
I've found this question: [How do I disable (video) thumbnails in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/152272/how-do-i-disable-video-thumbnails-in-windows-7) that points to this tool [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). It looks like this might be the solution I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to use it. For example it does not show anything from Adobe - does that mean that thumbnails for PDF files are not generated by the shell extension?

Comment: AFAIK it's all or nothing, unless there's some 3rd party app to do this (but I haven't seen one yet).