# Disable Windows Thumbnails for Specific Folders

Tags: windows, thumbnails, thumbnail-generator

I know there are methods for [Disabling thumbnails in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/133188/disable-thumbnails-in-windows-xp). But, I actually don't mind the feature, especially since Windows caches the thumbnails after the first pass.

But, I have directories where I would prefer to not have this feature, especially since I may not have write permission (causing Windows to try to scan the directory recursively on every visit - e.g. network shares, backup drives).

Can I disable the Windows thumbnail generation feature only for certain directories?

I am running Windows 7, but I would like to know for any/every version of Windows.