# No images’ thumbnails on network disk

Tags: images, nas, thumbnails

I bought network disk to build private cloud photo-archive. Unfortunately, there are icons instead the thumbnails in the Windows Explorer. I read some hints how to check these setting via Folder Options > View, but those don’t solve my problem. I will be thankful for any other advices, or links for free software, which is able to browse images on the network disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to try.

**A: Changing default folder settings.**

1. Go to Windows Explorer.
2. Choose the option 'Tools' at the top, next choose for the 'Folder' option in the menu.
3. Click the second tab called 'View'.
4. Make sure you deselect the option 'Always show icons, never thumbnails'.
5. Click on the 'Apply' button, also click on the 'Apply to Folders' button.

**B: Removing thumbnail cache (credits to [Simiil in question 71652](https://superuser.com/a/613868/65572))**

6. Open the taskmanager
7. Kill explorer.exe
8. Go to File -> new Task, run cmd
9. Navigate to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
10. Delete all .db files (del *.db)
11. Close cmd
12. Again, in the taskmanager go to File -> new Task, run explorer
13. Done.